# 1 step regexp_replace instead of two steps

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

`select replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(lower('new york,      ,ny usa '),r'[ ]+', ' '),', ,',',') c2`

**returns**
'new york,ny usa '

How can I do this in one step.
ie remove all the white space between ,              , and replace the result ,, with ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use;

```
([^,]+,)[, ]+
```

View [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7mjy8h/2)

`([^,]+,)` - Capture group which is returned with `\1` Match anything up to the next occurance of a comma and also capture the comma.

`[, ]+` - Exclude spaces and commas. The match fails at the next occurance of `[[:alpha:]]` characters

Comment: ```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(lower('new york,      ,ny usa '),r'([^,]+,)[, ]+', ',' ) x;
```

returns ,ny usa  it removes 'new york,

Comment: @DenisTheMenace `select REGEXP_REPLACE('new york, ,ny usa ', r'([^,]+,)[, ]+', r'\1');`

Comment: Great that works, any chance of an explanation so I can learn something?

Comment: @DenisTheMenace Sure, please check edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with capture groups:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('new york,      ,ny usa ', r'([^,]+)[, ]+(\w+) (\w+)', r'\1,\2 \3');
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tm9etr/1) showing that the pattern and replacement logic are working.

Comment: It does not work if the ,  , appears in a string that has more then 3 words.

Comment: ...then you should have included such sample data in your original question.

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: I created a new question with sample data. I did not realize that I needed my regex to do more until I ran it on multiple rows. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462959/1-step-regexp-replace-instead-of-two-steps-part-ii-replace-spaces-either-side-o

Comment: @DenisTheMenace I have given you an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462959/1-step-regexp-replace-instead-of-two-steps-part-ii-replace-spaces-either-side-o) as well.