# 1 step regexp_replace instead of two steps part ii, replace spaces either side of multiple words between comma delimiters

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

This a follow on from **"1 step regexp_replace instead of two steps"** as I did not provide enough sample data.
@hatless provided me with a solution for removing spaces between , , and also @lemon suggested I provide more data

spaces should be removed from either side of words between delimiters.
" new york "   should be "new york"
There could be spaces on either side of the word which should be removed but now between words.   The comma delimited string could have any number of delimiters up to 8 comma's.

I could do multiple nested replaces of ', '   and ' ,'  which would work for most cases except where there is more then one space before or after the comma. Can it be done with one regexp_replace or does it require multiple?

| **"RESULT BEFORE" ** |
| --- |
| "university of washington, seattle, washington" |
| "university of washington, seattle , washington" |
| "university of washington, , washington" |
| "university of washington, seattle, washington" |
| "university of new york,ny , usa" |
| "university of new york,new york , usa" |
| "university of new york, new york , usa" |

```sql
with t1 as 
(
select           1 id,"university of washington,           seattle, washington" location
union all select 2 id,"university of washington, seattle  , washington"
union all select 3 id,"university of washington,      , washington"
union all select 4 id,"university of washington, seattle            , washington"
union all select 5 id,"university of new york,ny  , usa"
union all select 6 id,"university of new york,new york  , usa"
union all select 7 id,"university of new york, new york  , usa"
)
select id,REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(location),r'([^,]+,)[, ]+', r'\1') location
from t1
order by 1;
```

| **"DESIRED RESULT" ** |
| --- |
| "university of washington,seattle,washington" |
| "university of washington,seattle,washington" |
| "university of washington,washington" |
| "university of washington,seattle,washington" |
| "university of new york,ny,usa" |
| "university of new york,new york,usa" |
| "university of new york,new york,usa" |

ACTUAL RESULT

| **id** | **location ** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | university of washington,seattle,washington |
| 2 | university of washington,seattle ,washington |
| 3 | university of washington,washington |
| 4 | university of washington,seattle ,washington |
| 5 | university of new york,ny ,usa |
| 6 | university of new york,new york ,usa |
| 7 | university of new york,new york ,usa |

Comment: How about `\s{0,},[\s,]{0,}`?  https://regex101.com/r/u5Zdw0/1

Comment: I'm not able to integrate this to the example. Its not clear enough to me. 

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER("university of washington,           seattle, washington"),
                          r'\s{0,},[\s,]{0,}'
                          ) AS location;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select id,
  regexp_replace(trim(location), r'\s*,\s*', ',') as location,
from t1
order by 1
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: ```
select id,
  replace(regexp_replace(trim(location), r'\s*,\s*', ','),',,',',') as location,
from t1
order by 1      
```
If I add the nested replace it works as the one of the criteria was replace empty ",..........," with ","

I can live with that if it can't be done in one pass.

Comment: i didn't get it :o) in  my view  - your question (as it is asked) is fully answered

Comment: I won't dispute it as the extra nested replace works, I was just wondering could it be done in one regexp. If you feel like answering great if not I will live with the nested version until I figure it out myself.

Comment: as I said  - i just simply didn't get what is the extra ask. usually it is hard to do via comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(location),
                          r'([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*',
                          r'\1,\2,\3') AS location
FROM t1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dpVf9e/1) showing that the regex replacement logic is working.

Comment: It would not work if there was more then two comma delimiters or if
The first delimiter looked like. 
"{spaces},seattle,washington"  
It seems like there is a specific regex for each column location?

Comment: Please forgive me, but this isn't fair.  My answer again works for all your sample data.  Third question coming?

Comment: I did specify
The comma delimited string could have any number of delimiters up to 8 comma's